# This code shows me that "CommandText has not been initialized"

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I want to check ManagerUsername and ManagerEmail in the database and the display a messagebox to show the user with their password.But when I execute the code it shows me that:

> "commandtext has not been initialized"

so I want to know how can I fix my code to display what I want. And also a way to improve my code to work more efficient

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Cybertronics
{
    public partial class passwordRecovery : Form
    {
        int pin = 0;
        private int _failedAttempts = 0;

        public passwordRecovery()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void passwordRecovery_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblAttempt.Visible = false;
        }

        private void btnBackLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loginFrm loginForm = new loginFrm();
            this.Hide();
            loginForm.Show();
        }

        private void btnSubmitEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string emailAddress = txtEmail.Text;
                string username = txtManagerUsername.Text;
                string password = "ChangeMe";
                CyberDatabase db = new CyberDatabase();
                db.OpenConnection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataReader reader;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ManagerUsername", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ManagerEmail", emailAddress);
                db.SetSqlCommand(cmd);
                reader = db.Select();

                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ManagerUsername from tblManagers WHERE ManagerUsername = @ManagerUsername and ManagerEmail = @ManagerEmail";
                db.SetSqlCommand(cmd);
                reader = db.Select();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    SqlCommand passwordUpdate = new SqlCommand();
                    passwordUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE tblManagers SET ManagerPassword=@Password WHERE ManagerUsername=@ManagerUsername and ManagerEmail=@ManagerEmail";
                    db.SetSqlCommand(passwordUpdate);
                    MessageBox.Show("your new password is:" + password);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (pin != 21)
                    {
                        _failedAttempts++;
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong password or username fail to login. you have" + (3 - _failedAttempts) + " attempts more.", "EPIC FAIL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                        if (_failedAttempts == 3)
                        {
                            Application.Exit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException sql)
            {
                CyberMethods.DisplayErrorMessage(sql.Message);//error message from cybermethods class for DB
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                CyberMethods.DisplayErrorMessage(exc.Message);//error message from cybermethods class
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, the first time you call db.SetSqlCommand() and db.Select(), you haven't initialized CommandText. So initialize it. What's the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the third`db.SetSqlCommand(cmd);` be `db.SetSqlCommand(passwordUpdate);` instead?

Comment: Not sure if it's important as I don't know the `CyberDatabase` type, but the first call to `SetSqlCommand` occurs before you set `CommandText`, the second one occurs after, though as Adam V points out, it also looks like you're using the wrong command. Also, look into: UI patterns; SOLID principles; N-Tier application architecture; and possibly principles of security. Oh, and the `using ()` statement.

Comment: Unrelated tip: you may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

your code is very messy and untidy. It is very error prone. Check the below sample code for best practices.

```
using (connection)
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT ManagerUsername from tblManagers WHERE ManagerUsername = @ManagerUsername and ManagerEmail = @ManagerEmail",
  connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }

    } 
}
```

you have multiple query statements. for the seperation of duties principles I suggest you to make 3 functions each seperate and call them respectively.

and It is wise to keep connection open then then close when all the operations finish.

**For solving your error**

before your first `db.SetSqlCommand(cmd);` just add your query statement with

```
cmd.CommandText = "select ....." ;
```

Comment: It's "best practice" to leak the `SqlCommand` object rather than also enclose it in `using`? That's news to me. Besides, this question is over a year old and the OP never seemed to return an answer to prompting.

Comment: Oh, I dont know how did I came this topic :) the code is from microsoft documentation. I personally use using block for SqlCommand as well but since there is using statement for opening connection, I dont see any downside for this.

Comment: And the DataReader is disposable as well. Once that's in a using block, there's no need to Close it. And you haven't shown adding the parameters which the OP has chosen a poor approach to... I will comment separately on that.

Comment: Please remember in future that a) if you're copying from MS documentation examples, they're frequently *not* examples of best practice (e.g. they only tend to emphasize one happy path) and b) You probably ought to link to and attribute it rather than appear to claim it as your own. I realise you've now changed it slightly from the original.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I generally try to add references. You are right. Yes I altered the code in order to apply best practive for DbConnection usage